# Conditional formatting is possible in Kendo Telerik grid when filtering?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I'd like to change background color of the rows in a Kendo Telerik grid, when applied a filter. I have and ASP.NET Mvc application. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you provide sample code that you have implemented? Also, when filter is applied, only filtered records are present in kendo grid so all the records will have the colors. Is this what you require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo's Grid has a built in option to change how the `TR`s are displayed, called [`rowTemplate`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/rowtemplate). The problem is that when you are using it, you have to deal with the whole row creation:

```
columns: [{
    title: "Id",
    field: "Id"
}],
rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#grid-template").html()),
filter: function() {
    rowAlt = 0; // This is a global variable
}
```

And the template:

```
<script id="grid-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
# let filter = $("\#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter();

#<tr class='#

if (++rowAlt % 2 == 0) {
    #k-alt #
}

if (filter != null) {
    #filtered-row#
}

#'><td>#=data.Id#</td>#
#<tr>##
</script>
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/eXAFIwoz)

---

Now, there is another way, which means to customize the grid's styles outside it, as proposed by other users already. It maked the grid's initialization simple and handles the styles after the rows are rendered(in [`dataBound`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/databound) event):

```
filterable: true,
columns: [{
    title: "Id",
    field: "Id"
}],
dataBound: function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if (this.dataSource.filter()) {
          this.tbody.find("tr").addClass("filtered-row");
        }
    }.bind(this), 1);
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/eXAFIwoz/2)

<sub>Note: I'm using `setTimeout` in the snippet above because sometimes the `dataBound` event is called before the DOM elements are finished rendering.</sub>

Both examples above I made it added a bg color in the row whenever the grid is filtered, you have to make your conditions based on `dataSource.filter()` result object, which contains all filter settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function to check if any filters exist on the kendo grid and then go through the existing grid rows and set the nearest  background-color to whatever you want.